# Generate AST for Java with ANTLR

Tags: antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

As far as I know, there are two mechanisms in ANTLR for building abstract syntax trees. I want to build a AST for Java source files.

Question: There are so many grammar rules in Java.g (java specification), it's a large work if I specify the AST generating rules for every item in Java.g. So I wondering if there is a ready-made one, and where can I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Java 1.5 grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars)<sup>1</sup> from the ANTLR Wiki generates an AST and also provides a tree grammar<sup>2</sup>.

1. `Java.g`
2. `JavaTreeParser.g`

---

#### 22 Aug 2014 - UPDATE

Since the original link appears to be dead, the grammar and tree grammar are available in a public Gist: https://gist.github.com/bkiers/741125a606954b24bbf4

Comment: Thank you so much.And is there also one for C?

Comment: @Fiary, a C pre-processor- and C grammar are available on the ANTLR wiki: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list

Comment: I am a little confused,what is the pre-processor used for?

Comment: @Fiary, _"The preprocessor handles directives for source file inclusion (#include), macro definitions (#define), and conditional inclusion (#if)"_ -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: Dear Bart, the link provided for Java 1.5 grammar does not exist anymore. any updates on that? what about antlr v4?

Comment: @MakanTayebi, yes, that is correct: it only works with ANTLR3.